# Time manipulation in PHP

Tags: php, trim

I'm curious what will be the output of this code? I can't understand what the time() is for, is that indication for the system time?

I edited the code sorry. This is the REAL code

```
$testnum = 4053000
$timetest = trim($testnum)



$rawnum = time() - ($timetest  * 60);
$diffdate = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $rawnum);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: run it and find out.

Comment: This code makes no sense since you never declared: `$timetest` and never used: `$testnum`

Comment: What will the output be? Why not run it?

Comment: rtm?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: The [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/) has an entry on [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).

Comment: I don't have a server side now that's why I can't check the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time() function returns the current time in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT). So what you see is an integer in seconds.

You define your timezone in the PHP.ini

Comment: Thank you for this I already now the value of the time()

Please check the code again, I add something the trim one.